# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_ref')

Tags: typescript, filter, mapping, typeerror, ref

[I'm getting the following error  when trying to filter products by category. Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjrOQ.png)

// index.tsx

```
const Home = ({ categories, products }: Props) => {
  console.log(products);

  const showProducts = (category: number) => {
    return products
      .filter((product) => product.category._ref === categories[category]._id)
      .map((product) => <Product product={product} key={product._id} />); // filters products by category
  };
```

Link to github repo https://github.com/angelDova/Apple

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Most likely `products` has an entry where `category` is undefined. Just use the optional chaining operator: `product.category?._ref`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining.